# Spring Transactional Multithreading Issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-transactions

I'm working on Payment Services, then I have an issue with the product's stock deduction during the payment process. I haven't figured out how I will do this for monolithic apps and distributed apps.

I'm using the below technology stacks;

- MySQL Database
- Spring Boot Framework
- Hikari Connection pool

These are entities.

Payment entity,

```
@Entity
public class Payment {

    private static final int HASH = 17;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private String bankResponse;
    private String integrationId;
```

Product Entity,

```
public class Product {

    private static final int HASH = 29;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    
    private String name;
    
    private String description;
    
    private Integer remainingStockCount;
    
    private BigDecimal price;
    
    @Version
    private Integer version;
```

In my case,

> Requirement is,
>
> 1. A product should not be sold for more than its stock.
> 2. Customers paying for the same product at the same time should not buy the product if the stock is depleted. (i.e. if there are 2 stocks left and 3 customers pay at the same time, first 2 successful should buy the product and the 3rd one should fail with an appropriate message.)
> 3. There is an async method to pay to the bank also after or before stock's deduction, please also consider it.

I have a lot of questions in there,

1. For a monolithic application, I think I can achieve it with Spring Transactional annotation, but we need to consider the solution with multithreading, so I don't know how I should deduct stock of the specific product, for the case that I mentioned above (second case).
2. For the distributed solution, we have a lot of servers, and a lot of applications that run in the server-like container, if I use Spring Transactional annotation, do I miss something or how can I do it for distributed systems?

For the sake of simplicity, I'm breaking my test methods here;

```
private void runPaymentForProduct(ProcessType processType) {
        List<CompletableFuture> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            CompletableFuture future = getFuture();
            futures.add(future);
        }
        futures.forEach(f -> CompletableFuture.allOf(f).join());
}

private CompletableFuture getFuture() {
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                            productPaymentService.pay(ID);
                }
        );
}
```

1. I have the payment method and added @Transactional annotation, but there is also an async method which is called in this transactional method, so I couldn't solve how I adapt these two processes harmonically.
2. I didn't want to use some concurrent collections or locking mechanism (read-write lock, synchronized) because even if we use monolithic applications, we can scale out our servers, that's why if we implement the single server-based solution, then it doesn't work with other servers together consistently.
3. By the way, if we implement this solution, let's assume that there are 100 users who call this endpoint, so we need to treat each user fairly, and give a response immediately.
4. When you answer these, could you please split the solution into two parts such as monolithic and distributed?
5. By the way, I can't change Hikari cp's settings like increasing the connection's timeout or increasing's the pool's size because we need to solve with other ways.
6. I'm using an optimistic lock mechanism, that's why Product Entity has @Version annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at Outbox pattern in case of distributed archiecture to do the transactions atomically and have maximum guarantees

refer: https://debezium.io/blog/2019/02/19/reliable-microservices-data-exchange-with-the-outbox-pattern/

For monolithic still I feel you should have application events that will be run in a sequence.

Comment: Hi, what about Saga Orchestrator Pattern when it comes to distributed approach? For monolithic, I couldn't understand your suggestion, could you open it up a little bit, what is application events, how can they work with @Transactional annotation and adapt to the multi-threading environment?